# What is the best way to model the business logic in Silex?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, soa, silex

I am not sure if I get the overall idea of Silex right where to store "business logic" which is not directly related to persistance, views, etc.

Example: In my "demo app" I needed a way to generate n unique numbers. I needed those numbers in a template to include partial templates. I created a RandomNumberServiceProvider which can return n numbers between x and y. In my $app-closure I used this service, assigned the random numbers to my twig template. Done.

More complex example: Let's say you have to develop a "complex" import function. You have to read data from the disk, validate the data, transform it somehow and finally store it into the database. Would you also create a ImportServiceProvider in this case which accesses other services (for persistance...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that, yes.

Though, instead of injection the complete service, I would recommend to inject just the factory. This way you can prevent the application logic from leaking in the controllers (or their equivalents), while at the same time keeping the domain objects as focused on the specific tasks.

```
$factory = new \My\ServiceFactory( /* ..dependencies */ );

// --- SNIP

$app->get('/foo/{bar}', function ($app, $bar) use ($factory) {

    $someService = $factory->build( ... );
    // do something with $someService

    return new Response(...);
});
```